# Should I test contrary cases?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, tdd, jestjs

i am using tdd and i not sure if i should test contrary cases or only expected case.

test 1

```
test('should render loading placeholder if isloading = true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <OrderDetails id="10" />
    );
    wrapper.setState({ isLoading: true });
    expect(wrapper.find(LoadingPlaceholder).length).toBe(1);
})
```

test 2

```
test('should not render loading placeholder if isloading = false', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <OrderDetails id="10" />
    );
    wrapper.setState({ isLoading: false});
    expect(wrapper.find(LoadingPlaceholder).length).toBe(0);
})
```

component

```
export default class OrderDetails extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  }
  props: Props;
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isLoading && (
           <LoadingPlaceholder />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

notes if only add the first test can pass the test with this for example
unexpecected pass test

```
export default class OrderDetails extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  }
  props: Props;
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <LoadingPlaceholder />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to test that your code handles unexpected cases.  If something can happen, such as withdrawing more money from your bank account then you have, then you want an error or exception generated.  This code should have TDD tests written to ensure it works correctly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have at least as many tests as possible (distinguishable) states for the unit under test. If there are two states (with isLoading being true or false) then you also need two tests, one for each possible state.

To put it differently and more formal: The number of tests for a unit should be greater or equal to the cyclomatic complexity of the unit.